# NSIS faulty installation location

Tags: nsis

I am loosing my mind trying to get my way around why my setup behaves differently on the target device

Nsis version: 3.04
My machine: Win 10 64bit Build 17763
Client machine: Win 10 32bit Build 10586

We have no control the client machine because they are for schools and we have to make the app work exactly on them devices like on our laptops no matter what.

`InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\OurApp`

on our machine this makes the setup install to

> C:\users\username\local\appdata\programs\OurApp

but on the client machine it installs to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\OurApp

I certainly can't understand why this keeps happening. The instructions to us that the data should not be accessible easily to the user except through the app we are building using .net. Then when the app is uninstalled it should clear the data it created. This only works when the app is installed in appdata location.

Any hints on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The initial investigation should be; is $Instdir set to the correct path **inside** the installer?

If you could write $Instdir to a log file on the client's machine that should help to narrow it down.

A common source of incorrect $Instdir is using `InstallDirRegKey` in combination with a existing older (possibly partial) install in a undesired directory.

If $Instdir is still c:\users... in your `Section` then you need to look at Windows, not NSIS. Tell them to look at the file properties of the installer .exe. Does it have any compatibility options applied? Do they have [other compatibility shims](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317510/how-to-use-the-compatibility-administrator-utility-in-windows) applied through group policy?

It might also be helpful if they could run Process Monitor and send you a pml log file. That should reveal if a install dir is read from the registry and the actual paths passed to the kernel when it creates files and directories.

Finally, make sure you have `RequestExecutionLevel user` in your script to avoid UAC interference.